# How to change segmented control design from square to circle

Tags: swift

How to change segmented control design from square to circle like this picture

from this picture
[image]

to this picture[image]

```
@IBOutlet var segmentedcontrol: UISegmentedControl!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    }
@IBAction func transction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)
{
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        addlater.isHidden = true
        morelike.isHidden = true
        parts.isHidden = false
    case 1:
        addlater.isHidden = true
        morelike.isHidden = false
        parts.isHidden = true
    case 2:
        addlater.isHidden = false
        morelike.isHidden = true
        parts.isHidden = true
    default:
        break}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have to create a UISegmentedControl from 0.

Another approach is use custom Buttons in a StackView.